# SQL Server - remote Oracle query extremely slow on date clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

Querying oracle from sql server client:

```
select top 10 * from [192.168.18.25]..ORDER where date >= '2019/01/01'
```

The above query takes about **400 seconds**, while in oracle client it takes only milliseconds.

What surprises me more is that when replace the `>=` with `<=`, or replace the date `2019/01/01` to a date that is less than the minimum date in the table, the query will again finish in milliseconds.

What may have caused the poor performance on `>= someDate` in the query ?

Comment: If you want understand your process, then you need look plan on Oracle DB. Perhaps slow execute here.

Comment: @RustamPulatov the same query finishes in milliseconds in oracle. So I don't think it has anything to do with query plan.

Comment: What do you mean by `sql server client`?

Comment: @TomC I mean any client that runs sql server sql, like Navicat, sql server management studio, etc.

Comment: So this is set up in sql server as a linked server I assume? I think you need to look at the actual query being run on the oracle database, as presumably some translation is going on. Is it possibly doing the equivalent of `cast date as varchar >= '2019/01/01'`. Maybe try explicitly casting the string to a datetime? Hard to know unless you can spy the actual oracle query.

Comment: @TomC Yes, I did come up with spying the actual oracle query, but don't know how. I'll try googling on that, thank you, tom.

Comment: is date column index ?how many records will be return with `date >= '2019/01/01'` when I remove top 10.

Comment: @KumarHarsh yes indexed. with date > 2019/01/01 still takes extremely long time, and numerous results.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I tried **`OPENQUERY`** and the performance problem is solved:

```
select top 10 * from openquery ( [192.168.18.25], 
'select * from order where date >= ''2019-01-01'' ')
```